# Regex to remove all digits from string except for specific words

Tags: java, regex, string

I'm trying to implement a regular expression that will remove all digits characters from a string but with exception for some particular word.For example, let say i have a string str1 like this :

```
    String str1 = "noDriver vehicle1 0.0 5 eric clarks 109.9819741964403 119.9819741964403 229.9639483928806 ";
  //what i would like is something like this , 
  //which will remove all words, integers,float in final it will have to return only "vehicle1"
  String str2= str1.replace(floats,"").replace(words,"").replace(integers,"");
```

at the end it should be returning only vehicle1 (which has both string and integer), could someone help please?

Attempts

```
str2=str1.replaceAll("\\s+"," ").replaceAll("\\d","")
```

Comment: What if there are 2 such words?. Should spaces be kept?. Do you need a list of such words or a string with all "other words" replaced?. What if there are other punctuation constructs in your string?

Comment: try ```String str1 = "noDriver vehicle1 0.0 5 eric clarks 109.9819741964403 119.9819741964403 229.9639483928806 ";
            String[] array = str1.split(" ");
            String s2 = "";
            for(String s:array){
                try{
                    double x = Double.parseDouble(s);
                }catch(Exception e){
                    s2 += " "+s;
                }                                                                                             
             }
            System.out.print(s2);```

Comment: @MATex - If you have an answer, *add it as an answer*, and not as a comment. Your comment is a mess tbh

Comment: I wanted to get only "vehicle1", erm the string will never contains any other special characters if thats you are asking :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to remove:

- The float `\d+\.\d+`
- The integer `\d+`
- The word `[a-zA-Z]+`

So you can write:

```
String str1 = "noDriver vehicle1 0.0 5 eric clarks 109.9819741964403 119.9819741964403 229.9639483928806 ";
String str2 = str1.replaceAll("\\b(\\d+\\.\\d+|\\d+|[a-zA-Z]+)\\b", "");

System.out.println(str2);
// Output: "vehicle1"
```